# I want to add a "counter" to this boolean method

Tags: java

Now, as you can see I am experimenting with Boolean methods. I have learned the charAt method through vowel detection, but I am not satisfied. I want to play around with it and figure out how to add a count for each vowel discovered.

But, I am not sure how to increase the count for each vowel.

In the wise words of Bill Lumbergh, if somebody could help me figure out how to do this count properly so it increases with every vowel added, that'd be greeeeeeeeeat.

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chap10Part4p2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner inputSentence = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
        sentence = inputSentence.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
            if (isVowel(sentence.charAt(i)))
                System.out.print(sentence.charAt(i));
            else if (i < sentence.length(); sentence.equals(isVowel);)
                count++;
        System.out.println(" There are " + count + " vowels in this sentence.");
    }

    static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this `else if (i < sentence.length(); sentence.equals(isVowel);)` compile?

Comment: He actually has a compiler error in the image attached.

Comment: It...Was my attempt at getting an increment of count onto the method. I know the code won't compile, because I made things more complicated than they had to be. I appreciate all the help here, though lol.

Comment: Rather than put `[solved]` in the title. Accept an answer below by clicking the checkmark if it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% sure on the purpose of the else if statement, its not valid syntax. Delete that and put the count underneath and that will count the total vowels.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
  if (isVowel(sentence.charAt(i))) {
      count++
   }
}

System.out.println(" There are " + count + " vowels in this sentence.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues with your code:

- Your code doesn't compile because of this invalid statement: `else if (i < sentence.length(); sentence.equals(isVowel);)`
- When you check the character to be a vowel, you don't increment `count`
- Its much more readable if you have a `{}` after your `for` loop so that you can exactly see what statements are within the loop.

Replace:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)

if (isVowel(sentence.charAt(i)))

System.out.print(sentence.charAt(i));

else if (i < sentence.length(); sentence.equals(isVowel);)
count++;

System.out.println(" There are " + count + " vowels in this sentence.");
```

With:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
    if (isVowel(sentence.charAt(i))){
        count++;
        System.out.print(sentence.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(" There are " + count + " vowels in this sentence.");
```

Comment: I must have done something to complicate this, the entire reason I was here was that my code kept printing : "There are 1 vowels in this sentence." When I used this variation. But perhaps I was just overlooking something, in any case thank you. Although I am a bit shaky with Boolean methods, so I will keep my questions more acute in the future. ^^

Comment: Well as per the image you attached, your code never compiled in the first place because of the `elseif` condition.

Comment: Oh, that I'm aware of. I was just here because I wanted to know how to properly add a count to this.

Comment: Even if the code complied, as soon as you check `if (isVowel(sentence.charAt(i)))`, you printed the character and didn't increment the count. That's why you didn't get the correct count.